# Fetching Doi metadata using python

Tags: python, python-requests, bibtex, cross-reference, doi

I want to fetch Bibtex citation from doi in Python. So the way I achieved it is by using this function:

```
   def BibtexFromDoi(doi):
       url =  "http://dx.doi.org/" + doi
       headers = {"accept": "application/x-bibtex"}
       r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
       return r.text
```

The problem with that, is that it takes so long to run this code, it takes from 10 to 15 minutes to get a response. ***I was wondering on what can be done to enhance the code and make it run faster***  In addition, I tried using Curl on the command line and it turns out to be faster with Curl, it only takes 1 to 2 seconds. I would like to achieve the same spead but on python.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried different DOIs? Can you post which one(s) you've tested?

Comment: Yes, I have tried different DOIs too, none of them worked properly. I suspect it's because of the URL, after trying with a different one `url = "http://api.crossref.org/works/" + doi +"/transform/application/x-bibtex"` it seem to work faster, but I still don't understand why.

Comment: That's odd. What python version are you running?

Comment: I am using Python 3.9.7

Comment: Does this also happen when you try a normal request with any other website? Maybe it's got something to do with the header request...

Comment: No, it doesn't happen with other websites